# How can I to correctly run an async thread in a test method?

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, async-await, xunit

I have this test that needs to run the `RunWebSocket` thread to make sure the `SendAsync` was received by my websocket. This works, but I am getting compiler warning [CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS4014)). Of course, I do not like warnings, so instead of ignoring it, I want to do it "right".

```csharp
[Fact]
public async void CabinetTagPushed_ShouldSendBroadcastToWebSocket()
{
    // arrange
    var websocket = Substitute.For<IWebSocket>();
    restinterface.RunWebSocket(websocket);

    // act
    restinterface.Cabinet_OnTagPushed(null, new TagEventArgs());

    // assert
    await websocket.Received().SendAsync(Arg.Any<ArraySegment<byte>>(), WebSocketMessageType.Text, false, CancellationToken.None);

    // this will end the RunWebSocket thread
    websocket.CloseStatus = WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure;
}
```

How can I create a test that kicks off an `async` thread correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your unit test method must be `async Task`, not `async void`.

Next, it's generally a good idea to `await` all tasks, to ensure you observe exceptions. Assuming the warning is on the `RunWebSocket` call, then that would look like this:

```csharp
[Fact]
public async Task CabinetTagPushed_ShouldSendBroadcastToWebSocket()
{
    // arrange
    var websocket = Substitute.For<IWebSocket>();
    var runTask = restinterface.RunWebSocket(websocket);

    // act
    restinterface.Cabinet_OnTagPushed(null, new TagEventArgs());

    // assert
    await websocket.Received().SendAsync(Arg.Any<ArraySegment<byte>>(), WebSocketMessageType.Text, false, CancellationToken.None);

    // this will end the RunWebSocket thread
    websocket.CloseStatus = WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure;

    await runTask;
}
```